# MIN function in SQL not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, subquery, min

I have a table that lists players of a game and the history of their level changes within the game (beginner, intermediate, advanced, elite, pro). I am trying to build a query that will accurately identify people who reached a level of advanced or higher for the first time so far in 2021 (it is possible for players to skip ranks, so I want the earliest date that they reached either he advanced, elite, or pro levels). I'm currently using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT p."ID", ra."NewRank", MIN(ra."EffectiveDate") AS "first_time_adv"
FROM rankachievement ra
JOIN player p
ON ra."ID" = p."ID"
WHERE ra."NewRank" IN ('Advanced',
        'Elite',
        'Pro')
GROUP BY 1, 2) AS t
WHERE t."first_time_adv" > '1/1/2021'
ORDER BY 1
```

Right now, this is pulling in all of the people who reached the advanced level for the first time in 2021, but it is also pulling in some people that had previously reached advanced in 2020 and have now achieved an even higher level- I don't want to include these people, which is why I had used MIN with the date.

For example, it is correctly pulling in Players 1 and 2, who both reached advanced on January 2nd, and player 4, who reached elite on January 4th after skipping over the advanced level (went straight from intermediate to elite). But it is also pulling in Player 3, who reached advanced on December 30th, 2020 and then reached elite on January 10th- I do not want player 3 to be included because they reached advanced for the first time before 2021. How can I get my query to exclude people like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting two results for Player 3... one with the advanced and one with the elite because you're grouping by `NewRank`. The one where Player 3 reached advanced gets removed from the result set by your `WHERE t.first_time_adv > '1/1/2021'` and the elite passes through. I suggest trying to use a `FILTER` and `OVER` with `MIN()`.

Your results from the inner query include something like this:

```
id | new_rank | MIN(EffectiveDate)
---+----------+-------------------
1  | advanced | the min date for this record (12/30/2020)
1  | elite    | the min date for this record (01/10/2021)
```

This is because you're getting the `MIN` while grouping both `ID` AND `NewRank`. You want the `MIN` over ALL records of that player. If you grouped by only `ID` you might get the behavior you were looking for but that would require you to remove the `NewRank` from the `SELECT` clause.

---

I suspect you want the rank in your final result set so try something like this:

```
WITH data AS
(
SELECT p."ID"
     , ra."NewRank"
     , ra."EffectiveDate"
     , MIN(ra."EffectiveDate")
       FILTER (WHERE ra."NewRank" = 'Advanced')
       OVER (PARTITION BY p."ID") AS "first_time_adv"
  FROM rankachievement ra
  JOIN player p ON ra."ID" = p."ID"
 WHERE ra."NewRank" IN ('Advanced', 'Elite', 'Pro')
)
SELECT *
  FROM data d
 WHERE d."first_time_adv" > '1/1/2021'
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Previously you were finding the `MIN(EffectiveDate)` for any `rank IN ('Advanced', 'Elite', 'Pro')`... now you're truly finding the `EffectiveDate` for when a player reached `'Advanced'`.

Comment: @J Spratt one more question for you. If I try to remove the NewRank column from the select clause and group by ID so that I only get one row for each player, I get an error that the effective date must appear in the group by clause or used in an aggregate function- but it is being used in an aggregate function, MIN. Is there something special I have to do to make this adjustment since I'm using FILTER and OVER?

Comment: I added an extra field in the `SELECT` clause in my example. You can remove that if you don't need it. Being that you're using a window function `OVER` you don't shouldn't need to use a `GROUP BY` clause because the window function is applied over the entire result set. The grouping is handled with the `PARTITION BY` in the window function. When using aggregate functions without `OVER` you'll need to group by everything else in the `SELECT` clause. I hope that answers your question.